# Может ли повторится ip адрес в сети одновременно

Tags: php, mysql, ip

Я писал систему логина на php. Единственным условием было, не использовать куки. Я сделал так, что система про логине будет добовлять ip и идентификатор в одну таблицу, который будет действителен 10 минут. Т.е. при каждом обновлении страници, скрипт будет спрашивать ip пользователя  и получать или не получать ответ из sql таблиц.
Может ли возникнуть ситуация, при которой два пользователя с двух разных устройств (компьютеров) зайти в один рабочий кабинет, т.е. иметь один динамический ip адрес? И стоит ли работать в этом ключе?

Comment: запросто. 1. пользователи могут попадать в сеть через роутер, который соберет их всех в один свой ip. 2. хакер может просто поставить себе такой же ip как у другой машины (и заодно mac), это приведет к тому, что со связью у обоих будут некоторые проблемы (будут рваться соединения), но подключиться по web и получить какие либо данные они смогут более менее спокойно, если трафик с них не особо интенсивный

Comment: Нет, не стоит. Почему (раз по каким-то причинам нельзя использовать cookies) вы не можете например передавать уникальные ключ сессии в урле?

Answer (score 1):

Если нельзя использовать куки, то могу предложить использовать Basic HTTP аутентификацию.

Ее можно настроить как на веб-сервере (например, у Апача - [тут](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html)), либо с использованием php-кода - [тут](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Comment: Или, как вариант, все же передавать сессионный ключ параметром в запросе. Или, как другой вариант, параметром в header'е запроса (такое, в принципе, можно даже при желании [замутить на javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214718/is-it-possible-to-alter-http-requests-header-using-javascript) для запросов со страницы).

Answer (score 0):

Если это локальная сеть, то вместо ip-адреса используйте мак, т.к. первый вариант неверное и ненадежное решение. А вообще на вашем месте я бы для каждого клиента генерировал хеш на основании тех же данных.

Comment: Это про какую локальную сеть вы говорите? Простенькую на свичах?

Comment: Про ту что LAN а не WAN. Думается мне что у вас первый вариант, т.к. во втором случае вообще безсмысленно было бы использовать IP-адресс для аутентификации пользователя.

Comment: Системы авторизации не могут полагаться на mac, потому что его можно изменить, причем это не намного сложнее смены ip. И случаи намеренной подмены mac-адресов внутри локалки мне встречались, только снятие таблицы коммутации со свитчей помогала вычислить ... И да, в локальной сети то же могут быть маршрутизаторы, через которые mac не пройдет ...

Comment: вы меня с топикстартером не перепутали? А так, у меня много вариантов :) И мне интересно, как вы будете "передавать" mac-адрес в пределах одной локальной сети, состоящей, например, из двух сетевых сегментов (vlan-ов). И сразу отвечу - никакой из вариантов аутентификации ни по ip, ни по mac-адресу неверный. По ним можно осуществлять некую предварительную фильтрацию, например, забанить некую сеть. А с mac-ами лучше вообще не связываться.

Comment: Здесь вопрос не в том как получить мак адрес. Я лишь указал что в данном контексте использовать его будет куда эфективней чем IP и не надо говорить что его изменить так же легко. А то что оба варианта не верны это факт, поэтому использовать можно хеш-токен, собственно о котором и написал.

Comment: Да, изначально вопрос в другом. Но у вас в ответе написано - `я бы для каждого клиента генерировал хеш на основании тех же данных`. Каких? ip-адреса клиента и его mac-адреса? Если да, то ваш ответ как раз и сводится к проблеме `получить mac клиента`. Если нет, то напишите в ответе подробнее, что за "исходники" вы предлагаете в качестве аутентификации. В ответе @Mike уже написано - как меняются mac-адреса в локальной сети и без рукотворного вмешательства.

Comment: У топикстартера уже есть какая-то реализация и мой ответ был основан исходя из этого. Я указал только более надежный вариан, чем есть. Да и мак адресс это не ip и на его смену не влияют dhcp и другие службы.